# When does wordpress process &lt;!--nextpage--&gt;

Tags: filters

when does <!--nextpage--> get processed by wordpress filtering. i am adding  multiple paged posts in post content on the content_save_pre and this is good for rendering my shortcodes, but <!--nextpage--> doesnt get processed and shows up as an html comment

Comment: As Rarst said, it is parsed on displaying the post, so your `content_save_pre` should be a good place to insert it. Does it show in the editor if you edit the post again? Can you see a difference in the database between a break entered in the editor and one by your code? Are you sure you used `<!--nextpage-->` and no spaces in that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by rendering shortcodes at that stage, they are usually rendered when content is retrieved for display.

*nextpage* tag is processed in `setup_postdata()` ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/query.php#L2838) ), which is called by `the_post()`. In other words - during Loop.

Comment: I assume he means that he inserts shortcodes and `<!--nextpage-->` tags in the `content_save_pre` hook, and the shortcodes get processed like they should, but the page breaks not.

Comment: yes Jan you are correct, @Rarst i will give setup_postdata() a try. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As an update. content_save_pre does process <!--nextpage-->  i had the <!--nextpage--> tag inside the shortcode function, once i moved them outside, all was good.